# Symfony2 execute SQL file in Doctrine Fixtures Load

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I'm migrating an old web app based on SQL Server and ASP to Symfony2 and MySQL. I made some queries and export old data to individual SQL files. 
How can I execute thoses files in my fixtures, when I run the command

```
$php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Now I have some fixtures that works directly with Doctrine ORM and entities, but I have a lot of data to import.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I find a good solution. I didn't find an `exec` method in class `ObjectManager`, so... this work very well for me.

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    // Bundle to manage file and directories
    $finder = new Finder();
    $finder->in('web/sql');
    $finder->name('categories.sql');

    foreach( $finder as $file ){
        $content = $file->getContents();

        $stmt = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getConnection()->prepare($content);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

In this solution your fixture class has to implement the `ContainerAwareInterface` with the method

```
public function setContainer( ContainerInterface $container = null )
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Comment: use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

Comment: We can use `new \Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo('web/sql/categories.sql', '', '')` instead of `Finder`

Answer (score 12):

You can load the file contents as a string, and execute native SQL using the EntityManager:

```
class SQLFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{    
  $filename = '/path/to/sql/file.sql';

  public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
    $sql = file_get_contents($filename);  // Read file contents
    $manager->getConnection()->exec($sql);  // Execute native SQL

    $manager->flush();
  }

  public function getOrder() {
    return 99;  // Order in which this fixture will be executed
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no method `getConnection` under ObjectManager. my IDE screams at me. The code runs because I don't get an Object Manager. I get an EntityManager instead.......

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Zend Framework 2.5.3 using [Doctrine Data-Fixtures](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures).

Not sure if this applies to the given answers, but they are trying a bit too hard. If you inspect the given `$manager` object, you'll find that it already is the `EntityManager` (of `interface ObjectManager`) (at least, in ZF2). As such you're able to get the `Connection` directly and it's possible to execute without using `$this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')`

Below a snippet which I use for creating the first user "system", with a `createdBy` FK reference to itself.

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (
              id, username, email, display_name, `password`, created_by) 
            VALUES (:id, :username, :email, :display_name, :password, :created_by)';

    $password = $this->createSuperDuperEncryptedPassword();

    // $manager === `EntityManager|ObjectManager`, `->getConnection()` is available
    $stmt = $manager->getConnection()->prepare($sql); 

    $stmt->bindValue(':id', 1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', 'system');
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', 'system@system.test');
    $stmt->bindValue(':display_name', 'system');
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', password );   
    $stmt->bindValue(':created_by', 1);        // Self reference
    $stmt->execute();
}
```